# Rcaller simple code - Error loading Runiversal

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I have the follow Java code that uses [Rcaller](http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/).

```
RCaller caller = new RCaller();
RCode code = new RCode();

caller.setRscriptExecutable("/usr/bin/Rscript");

code.addRCode("install.packages(\"bbmle\")");
caller.redirectROutputToConsole();
caller.runOnly();
```

Essentially, I'm trying to run Java code that installs an R package (because later I will run R code within Java that requires this package).

When I run this code, I get the following output in Java

```
Error:Loading required package: Runiversal
```

However, I do have the `Runiversal` package on my Mac. Any ideas what this means, and why I'm not actually seeing any `R` output of the `install.packages` method, which is normally quite verbose?

---

UPDATE: I should note that even simple code such as the following results in the same error:

```
code.addRCode("x = c(1,2,3)");
code.addRCode("y = c(2,3,5");
code.addRCode("x+y");
caller.redirectROutputToConsole();
caller.runOnly();
```

---

UPDATE: I should also mention that the following works great:

```
StringBuffer allCode = readFile("temp.R");
code.setCode(allCode);

double[] xvector = new double[]{1,3,5,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,21,22,25,27,25,34,39,31};
double[] yvector = new double[]{6,7,5,6,5,6,6,7,6,8,9,21,20,19,23,24,29,38,30};
code.addDoubleArray("X",xvector);
code.addDoubleArray("Y",yvector);

code.addRCode("fun(X,Y)");
```

temp.R:

```
fun = function(x,y) {
    return(lm(y~x))
}
```

Java output:

```
Output:
Output:Call:
Output:lm(formula = y ~ x)
Output:
Output:Coefficients:
Output:(Intercept)            x  
Output:      2.445        0.825  
Output:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R loads package from the libraries. If the library that you installed the Runiversal package into is not being searched by the R process started under Java, that could result in the error message you're seeing.

So: what is the directory path (i.e., library) that the Runiversal package is installed in? Possibly related to this is what user installed the R package, and what user is running the Java code.

Comment: Runiversal is in the same spot that all my packages are in. /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/. I am the user that installed the package (directly through R) and I am the user that is running the Java code. Is there a way I can check to see if this location is being searched by the R process started under Java?

Comment: The R function .libPaths() will return a character vector of library directories.

Comment: Are you using Rscript as the setRscriptExecutable in both cases above?

Comment: Rscript has an argument called default-packages, so you may need to load Runiversal via that argument? Just a guess here, try the following from the command line:  Rscript --default-packages='Runiversal' -e 'search()'  vs. Rscript -e 'search()'

Answer (score 0):

The 2.2 version of RCaller library does not require the R package Runiversal. A compact version of R to XML converters are implemented in the package. Try it out [here](http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/2014/04/rcaller-220-is-released.html)